# Can a man interfere in the personal affairs of a husband and his wife if the husband has been torturing his wife while she remains silence?

Tags: sharia, nikah

If the husband has been physically assaulting his wife, can a man interfere in their life and come to rescue to the woman? What is the correct procedure to salvage the wife?

Comment: Yes he can. He can do so by calling the authorities to help that woman. Just remember he can interfere individually though (only authorities)

Comment: How is this related to Islam?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unclear what this has to do with Islam specifically.